# How can I upload file names?

Tags: html, jsp

I'm a beginner in JSP.

I used `getFileNames()`, but I could not get file names (only got "browse").

I replaced `getFileNames()` with `getParameteNames()` but it doesn't work either.

How can I upload filenames?

**html**

```
<form name="fileForm" id="fileForm" method="POST" action="proc.jsp">
<input type="browse" type="file" multiple />
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

**JSP**

```
<%
String uploadPath="D:\\upload\\";
int size=10*1024*1024;

try{
    MultipartRequest multi=new MultipartRequest(request,uploadPath,size,"UTF-8", new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());

    Enumeration params=multi.getParameterNames();

    while(params.hasMoreElements()){

    }

    }   catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }   finally {

    }


%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

`<input type="file" name="browse"  multiple />`

**with**

`<input type="browse" type="file" multiple />`

Comment: Thx. I modified HTML reference to your answer. But it didn't work.